# Jquery Issue issue to send custom attribute value and option value comma seperated

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select id="jform_subject_type_id" name="jform[subject_type_id]" class="form-control" multiple="true">
  <option value="36" subject_country_id="1">Arts and Crafts(India) 
  </option><option value="37" subject_country_id="2">Computer sklls(Germany)</option>
  <option value="37" subject_country_id="1">Computer sklls(India) 
  </option><option value="33" subject_country_id="1">Academic(India) </option>
</select>
```

I have a multi-selected select box which, I am want to send selected option value and it's custom attribute "subject_country_id" to ajax request where I will make php request to get data according to their country and it's subject type value.
Can anyone help with this to send a key-value pair in ajax to make it work?
I am trying this

```
var subject_type_id=jQuery('#jform_subject_type_id').val(); // I will get value comma seperated.

var subject_country=jQuery('#jform_subject_type_id option:selected').attr('subject_country_id'); // I can't get custom attribute comma sepetaed

alert(jQuery("#jform_subject_type_id option:selected").map(function(){return this.text }).get().join(', ')); // If I use this code then i will get selected option text comma seperated.
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Anil Singh  If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how you can do that:- [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the value of selected options. Use this script.

```
var subject_country_id = [];
jQuery('#jform_subject_type_id option:selected').each(function(){
    subject_country_id.push(jQuery(this).attr("subject_country_id"));
  });
```

In `subject_country_id` you will get the values of selected option's custom attribute.

Codepen link

https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/eMvLqb